# kpfonts and Computer modern

Tags: fonts, typography

there are typographical contraindications to use kpfonts for the text and standard Computer modern for the Math mode?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[nomath,fulloldstylenums,fulloldstyle]{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
ciaostffi

\[\int a+b=c^2\sum\partial\nabla\psi\ell\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's always better not to mix fonts in the text body. If you type a variable name or inline formula, it will definitely look awkward. May I ask why you want two different fonts?

Answer (score 4):

use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nomath,fulloldstylenums,fulloldstyle]{kpfonts}
...
```

then you'll get:

```
voss@shania:~/Test> pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
JONXPB+Kp-Companion-Regular          Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
SDCAJC+Kp-Regular                    Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
YPARFD+Kp-Expert-Regular             Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
WHFDFR+LMMathExtension10-Regular     Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
IPZDPD+LMMathItalic10-Regular        Type 1            yes yes no       8  0
NZUYHE+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            yes yes no       9  0
SDXHST+LMRoman7-Regular              Type 1            yes yes no      10  0
HXDVWF+LMMathSymbols10-Regular       Type 1            yes yes no      11  0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "typographical counter-indications".

It is certainly the case that the `kpfonts` text-mode and math-mode fonts are quite different from their Computer Modern and Latin Modern counterparts. The Kepler font, being derived from the famous `Palatino` font, is best classified as "oldstyle" or "Garalde". The Computer Modern fonts are, well, "modern" in style. Three of most readily apparent differences are:

- modern fonts tend to feature a higher ratio between the thickest and thinnest parts of each letter, leading to a higher "contrast" within letters
- the Computer/Latin Modern fonts are also noticeably less "dark" in overall appearance than are the Palatino/Kepler fonts when set on a page
- the x-heights of the two font families (when set at the same *nominal* size of, say, 10 points) also differ noticeably (kpfonts/Palatino featuring the larger x-heights)

Whether the presence of such differences amounts to a clear-cut counter-indication against mixing these two fonts in a single document, I will have to leave up to you to decide. It's often said that typographic "rules" are meant to be broken -- or at least bent -- at times. However, as with most rules, it's probably also true that the bending or breaking of typographic rules better be done deliberately and with a clear reason in mind.